# Entity Framework Count and List concurrently

Tags: entity-framework

I have a request handler which takes a criteria, add some other criterias related to user authorization and then returns the number of records that match that criteria along with the required page.

```
    public PageResult GetPage<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, int start, int count)
    {
         var query = db.Set<T>();
         //apply some criterias, sorting, etc to criteria
                    recordCount = query.Count();
                    if (start != 0)
                        query = query.Skip(start);
                    if (count != 0)
                        query = query.Take(count);
                    var data = query.ToList();
         return new PageResult {rowCount = recordCount, data = data};
    }
```

I am using EF version 6, is there an easy way of running the Count and Top x queries async or in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run two queries asynchronously on the same `DbContext` object, so the only way would be creating two contexts (one for each thread).

More info here: http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/04/01/async-processing.aspx

Comment: PLINQ is for Linq to Objects, not for Linq to Entities